# SSIS - Need to connect to multiple databases in Execute SQL Task

Tags: t-sql, ssis, database-connection

I am trying to use an Execute SQL task to run a T-SQL script into a table. The T-SQL is using multiple databases to gather information from. I have tried to use the Database Name before he Table Name however I can only connect to some of the databases with SQL Authentication.

Any ideas how I can get around this?

Comment: What's the error message? Does the user have permissions to connect/query those databases?  Does the query work in SSMS with the same user?

Comment: There is no way to get around not being able to access databases that you don't have permission to.   You need to give your package permission to access those databases.

Answer (score 0):

You can use only one database per task. To do this you should create multiple execute taks. Unless you have a linked server to the other databases.

Answer (score 0):

- If the databases are within a same SQL Instance just use the [Db].[SCHM].[TB] and execute your script under a user with having a proper access to all the DB and tables.
- If they are in different SQL Instances or a SQL on another machine you can first create a LinkedServer with enough authority and then use that in your query. So it would be: [LinkServer name].[DB].[Schm].[Table]  for the tables on the another SQL box.
- Third option if you have different SQL instances/SQL on another machine, Import/Export the data into a physical table/s in your SQL and then try to write up and run your query.

Answer (score -1):

In case of needing to access different instances, I have found a better solution without altering security settings by taking advantage of variables.  Dynamically build the query from various variables, and then combine them to execute on the main instance.  It works for me beautifully.